# can't pass locals to parital Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, renderpartial

I have a partial `_new_user_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@user, :remote => true, :html => {:id => 'new_user_form'}) do |f|%>
  <strong><%= :form_text %></strong>
  <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder =>  get_placeholder_text(@board), :size => "30" %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :role, role %>
  <%=f.submit "SAVE", :class => "button-small" %>
<% end %>
```

In the show.rb I want to use it and pass in some partial variables as follows:

```
<%= render  'users/new_user_form', :locals=> {:role => "Celebrant" } %>
```

However I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `role' for #<#<Class:0x00000103d5e8b0>:0x00000103d5b930>
```

I read the documents about passing in locals and this seems correct. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're combining the short and long forms. Either of these are correct (identical):

```
render 'my_partial', :foo => 'bar'

render :partial => 'my_partial', :locals => { :foo => 'bar' }
```

Comment: Thanks Coreyward for getting back so fast. It worked using the first line.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're calling `render` incorrectly. From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper.html#method-i-render):

> If no options hash is passed or `:update` specified, the default is to render a partial and use the second parameter as the locals hash.

So you end up going down this branch in the source:

```
view_renderer.render_partial(self, :partial => options, :locals => locals)
```

and that makes your call the same as this:

```
render :partial => 'users/new_user_form', :locals => { :locals => { :role => 'Celebrant } }
```

Note the extra level of nesting for `:locals`. Try this:

```
render 'users/new_user_form', { :role => 'Celebrant' }
```

I'm looking at (and using) 3.1 so your version might be a little different.

Comment: Thanks Mu is too short. The explanation is fantastic.